# Get filetype by extension or filename in vimscript

Tags: vimscript

Is there a way to get filetype for given extension or filename

For example:

```
let my_f='text.rb'
let my_ft=GetFileType(my_f)
echo my_ft
" should output ruby
```

Comment: easiest would be to load the file for editing and check the `filetype` option. Next best option, would be to parse the filetype.vim file (e.g. the filetypedetect autocommand group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Christian said, parsing the expression won't be the easier way. I'd even say that's insufficient. Some filetypes share the same file extension. In that case, vim parses a few lines from the files to deduce exactly their filetype.

Otherwise, you could indeed parse `filetype.vim`, but instead, I'd parse the result of `execute('autocmd filetypedetect')` with `filter()`. If for your extension you get a `setf {filetype}` then you have a direct hit. Otherwise, it means vim does some magic with lines of the file to disambiguate the information.

```
let ext = expand('%:e') 
let matching = uniq(sort(filter(split(execute('autocmd filetypedetect'), "\n"), 'v:val =~ "\*\.".ext')))

if len(matching) == 1 && matching[0]  =~ 'setf'
   return matchstr(matching[0], 'setf\s\+\zs\k\+')
endif
throw "sorry, I can't know"
```

PS: `execute()` requires vim7.4-2008. With earlier versions we have to play with `:redir`. See [`lh#askvim#exe()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/askvim.vim#L59)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set `filetype` for cases like "myfile.ext.template" you could use this

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.template execute "doautocmd filetypedetect BufRead " . fnameescape(expand("<afile>:r"))
```